# Native session usage in Slim framework

Tags: php, session, slim

I am new to slim framework. I have to session in slim framework. I am using Native PHP session in slim framework.

I have added this line in index.php before slim is instantiated:

```
<?php 
session_cache_limiter(false); 
session_start();
```

And i have a route defined in which i will be inserting data and redirecting to the url as below:

```
 $app->post('/users', function()use($app) {
    $useradd = new \app\User();
    $session = new \app\Session();

    $data = $useradd->addUsers();

    if($session->getId('useraddsuc')) {
        $app->response->redirect('../templates/user?success');
    } else {
       $app->response->redirect('../templates/user?fail');
    }
});
```

And the session is set in `addUsers` method as below:

```
    function addUsers() {
        try {
            $db = new \app\Config();

            $name = $db->escape($_POST['name']);
            $email = $db->escape($_POST['email']);
            $date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $tmp_id = $db->random_id(8);


$sql = "INSERT INTO app_user (user_name, user_email, user_role, user_date_create, user_tmp_id, user_date_modified) VALUES ('$name','$email','store_admin','$date_created','$tmp_id','$date_created')";

            $query = $db->insertQuery($sql);
            $session = new \app\Session();
            $session->setId('useraddsuc', 'user account added successfully');
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
```

When the session is set its redirecting to the right path as its mentioned.
But not able to access the session variable in the url path after redirecting.
i.e. in `templates/user/index.php` not able to access session variable that is set in the `addUsers` method. Below code is written to check session in `templates/user/index.php` but this is not working. Kindly help!!

Code to check session in `templates/user/index.php`

```
   <?php if(isset($_SESSION['useraddsuc'])) {    ?>
    echo "User added successfully!!"
    <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. Adding below lines will detect the session.

```
<?php @ob_start();

if(session_status()!=PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
session_start();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['useraddsuc'])) {    
echo $_SESSION['useraddsuc'];
} 

?>
```